# Average of a measure in power pivot

Tags: indexing, average, powerpivot, measure

I have  the following measure in my data model:

Ratio Litiges et Livraisons:=CALCULATE(SUM('Nb lignes en litige'[Nbre ligne comm en litige])/SUM('Qté réception'[Qté reçue]))

It gives me the index between the number of complaints and the volume of receptions.

I have different groups of providers and I want to calculate the average index of all and of each group.

When I try to create a new measure with the average function I get the message: The average function only accepts a column reference as an argument.

How can I calculate the average of this index measure (Ratio litiges et livraisons)? Thanks!